# Windows, NetBeans: Where's the php.ini?

Tags: php, netbeans

I have been away from PHP for quite a while, so hopefully this is a simple oversight.  But, I am not able to include the MySQL extension.

**Setup**

- Windows 8 Pro 64-bit
- NetBeans 7.2.1 (Built-in PHP Web Server)
- MySQL
- PHP 5.4.8

**Problem**

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

**Attempted Resolution**

- Copy *php.ini-development* to *php.ini* (files are where I installed PHP, E:\Software\php-5.4.8-Win32-VC9-x86)
- Edit *php.ini* by uncommenting the lines

  - extension_dir = "ext"
  - extension=php_mysqli.dll
- Added E:\Software\php-5.4.8-Win32-VC9-x86\ext to NetBeans PHP Include Path in Project Properties

Still fails with the same error

**Diagnostic Output**

Added a call to *phpinfo()* at the top of the page.  That indicates:

Configuration File (php.ini) Path **C:\Windows**

*However*, there is no *php.ini* in C:\Windows.  In fact, I searched all disks and found only the one *php.ini* file that I previously edited.

**Question**

Where is NetBeans / PHP pulling the configuration from when I run my project, and how can I edit that configuration?

Comment: The output of phpinfo() should tell you which ini file(s) were actually being parsed as well. http://i.stack.imgur.com/IviVP.png

Comment: @MikeB: It does not.  The output is only *C:\Windows*

Comment: Did you restart your web server?

Comment: @AlexP: That was it!  (Sort of... I'm using the NetBeans internal web server and had to restart NetBeans).

Comment: **downvoter**: From the FAQ *Above all, be honest. If you see misinformation, vote it down. Add comments indicating what, specifically, is wrong. Provide better answers of your own. Best of all — edit and improve the existing questions and answers!*

Comment: Why on earth would you guys vote to migrate this to Server Fault? It's off topic there **and** it already had an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart the web server/netbeans :-)

Comment: For PHP configuration you do not need to restart Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no php.ini file listed as being loaded by `phpinfo()` then there is not one. PHP will use default values for everything in this case. Anything that needs to be overridden can be placed in a new php.ini in one of the locations specified by `phpinfo()` as being scanned for ini files.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be what is happening here.  Editing the one php.ini and restarting NetBeans caused the PHP configuration to change.  I suppose NetBeans is doing something behind the scenes to configure PHP based on that .ini file, just based on what I am observing.

Answer (score 0):

From your description what you did to *php.ini* (excerpt):

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
                   ^
```

But in your question you write:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

Which is a different extension, namely on windows:

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
```

(without the `i`)

Probably it's just a little oversight you're missing here. You have two options then:

1. Port the code to `mysqli_*` functions (recommended for new code)
2. Activate the old `php_mysql.dll` extension (for legacy code)

Do what fit's your needs. On windows, the folloing filenames (search your disk) are interesting:

- `php.ini` - normally inside the directory where you find `php.exe`
- `php_mysql.dll` - normally inside the `ext` subdirectory of the just said directory.